# При авторизации через VK черный экран с надписью erorr

Tags: дефект, вконтакте, способы-входа

Я уже почти полгода не могу войти в свой основной аккаунт! Что это за безобразие?
Я создавал похожий вопрос, сообщение на мета, но на него спустя время просто забили. Я удалил его сейчас, чтобы не мозолил глаза.

Итак, суть проблемы. Нажимаю войти через vk - черный экран, маленькая надпись error. Я думал, мб кэш. Удалил куки, ctrl+f5. Нажимаю войти, открывается форма для входа, я авторизовался - черный экран и error.

Пробовал в другом браузере - та же история. На телефоне я всё еще в аккаунте, выходить не охота.

Когда я смогу войти в свой аккаунт? Или можно изменить способ входа. Например, вместо этого аккаунта я хочу входить в свой аккаунт @Color kat